# Get Geopoints from SQlite DB

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I created an SQlite database to store on it all latitudes and longitudes to display them in map. For the add of the values i didn't encouter any problem, i used this code:

```
CoordBD CoordBd = new CoordBD(this);
Coordo coordo = new Coordo(36.869686,10.315642 );
CoordBd.open();
CoordBd.insertCoordo(coordo);
```

But i don't know how to insert them one by one in map, i usually/manually make this:

```
GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(microdegrees(36.86774),microdegrees(10.305302));
pinOverlay.addPoint(point2);
```

How to browse all the database and add all the Geopoints automatically?
Thank you.
**EDIT**: Is that true?

```
CoordBD CoordBd = new CoordBD(this);
        CoordBd.open();
        Coordo coordo = new Coordo(36.869686,10.315642 );
        CoordBd.insertCoordo(coordo);
        CoordBd.close();

        maMap = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.myGmap);
        maMap.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        ItemizedOverlayPerso pinOverlay = new ItemizedOverlayPerso(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker));

        String[] result_columns = new String[] {COL_LATI, COL_LONGI};
        Cursor cur = db.query(true, TABLE_COORD, result_columns,
        null, null, null, null, null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
                int latitude = cur.getColumnIndex("latitude");
                int longitude = cur.getColumnIndex("longitude");
                GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(microdegrees(latitude),microdegrees(longitude));
                pinOverlay.addPoint(point);
            cur.moveToNext();
        }
        cur.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting myself from my reply to you on the `android-developers` Google Group, since [you elected to cross-post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4d338a117a13c946):

1. Pass a `Cursor` to your `ItemizedOverlay` that contains your coordinates, retrieved from your database
2. Implement `size()` in your `ItemizedOverlay` to return `getCount()` from the `Cursor`
3. Implement `getItem()` in your `ItemizedOverlay` to `moveToPosition()` on the `Cursor`, read out the latitude and longitude, convert to microdegrees, create a `GeoPoint`, and return it
4. Use the `ItemizedOverlay` on your `MapView`

Comment: Mark Murphy ;). As i said there, can you please post me a link of how making this in Java code ?

Comment: All the steps and how converting them to Java code. If there is some examples it'll be 100% clear.

Comment: @androniennn: Um, to be blunt, this is not that hard. You claim to already know how to work with a database and how to work with an `ItemizedOverlay`. If those claims are true, tying those together this way should not be especially difficult for you. I do not have an example of a database-backed `ItemizedOverlay` lying around -- perhaps you can find one via a Google search.

Comment: Please see my edited post. What do you say about the code? correct? Thank you very much.

Comment: I have a FC caused by this line: `Cursor cur = db.query(true, TABLE_COORD, result_columns,` Any idea please ??

Comment: @androniennn: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace assocaited with your "FC".

Comment: The important thing that the code looks correct, especially the line caused by FC. Right ?

Comment: @androniennn: I have no idea. I wish you luck in your Android development efforts; I am no longer going to continue in this comment chain.

Comment: I'm trying to learn and i wish having some help. There is no one to guide me :\. Anyway, thank your for your answers.